# Configuring arangodb failed in CentOS 5

Tags: arangodb

I need to porting ArangoDB to centos 5 system, I have updated python to 2.7.13 and cmake to 3.91, but during cmake executing, below error message appeared

```
-- Will compile in hand-optimized assembler code for CRC32.
CMake Error at arangod/CMakeLists.txt:448 (target_compile_features):
  target_compile_features The compiler feature "cxx_constexpr" is not known
  to CXX compiler

  "GNU"

  version 4.1.2.


-- building for git revision: 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

does someone know how about this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArangoDB requires a compiler which supports C++ 11 standard. You will need gcc 4.8 and above. The above error is informing you that your compiler does not recognise the `constexpr` keyword. Also please note that Centos 5 has expired as of March 2017 (https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=57398) and should really not be operated anymore. However, if there really is no way around Centos 5, here is a docker container offering gcc 4.8 in Centos 5.